# Easiest way to plot data from JSON with matplotlib?

Tags: python, json, pandas, matplotlib, plot

So I have some data in json format, here's a snippet:

```
"sell": [
           {
               "Rate": 0.001425,
               "Quantity": 537.27713514
           },
           {
               "Rate": 0.00142853,
               "Quantity": 6.59174681
           }
]
```

What's the easiest way to access Rate and Quantity so that I can plot it in Matplotlib? Do I have to flatten/normalize it, or create a for loop to generate an array, or can I use pandas or some other library to convert it into matplotlib friendly data automatically?

I know matplotlib can handle inputs in a few ways

```
plt.plot([1,2,3,4], [1,4,9,16])

plt.plot([1,1],[2,4],[3,9],[4,16])
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The simpliest is [`DataFrame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html) constructor with [`DataFrame.plot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html):

```
import pandas as pd

d = {"sell": [
           {
               "Rate": 0.001425,
               "Quantity": 537.27713514
           },
           {
               "Rate": 0.00142853,
               "Quantity": 6.59174681
           }
]}

df = pd.DataFrame(d['sell'])
print (df)
     Quantity      Rate
0  537.277135  0.001425
1    6.591747  0.001429

df.plot(x='Quantity', y='Rate')
```

EDIT:

Also is possible use [`read_json`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_json.html) for `DataFrame`.

Comment: Brilliant, I'm just getting acquainted with pandas and dataframes. For anybody else who reads this, be sure that you include: 

import pandas as pd

Comment: It depends of structure of `json`. If structure is simple, `read_json` works perfectly. If more complicated or nested, solution also works, but is necessary some transforming.

Comment: Thanks so much! What would format look like if I wanted to append a timestamp to my dataframe?


df = pd.DataFrame(jsonsource["result"]["sell"],timestamp)

Comment: Do you need append scalar value to new column?

Comment: If yes, then need `df['timestamp'] = timestamp`